# How to read some images from a local file then display on a web page by using flask and python3?

Tags: python, flask

I want to read some images(.jpg) from a local file path, then display those images on a web page(127.0.0.1:8000) by using flask and python3.I have already display single image on web page by use the following code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
 
def return_img_stream(img_local_path):
    import base64
    img_stream = ''
    with open(img_local_path, 'rb') as img_f:
        img_stream = img_f.read()
        img_stream = base64.b64encode(img_stream).decode()
    return img_stream
 
 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    img_path = 'D:\\1111\\1.jpg'
    img_stream = return_img_stream(img_path)

    return render_template('index.html',img_stream=img_stream)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='127.0.0.1',port=8080)
```

How should I modify this code？

Comment: Return a page of HTML which contains a line like  `<img src=“IMAGE.JPG”>` for each image. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: As @MarkSetchell said to return the HTML with the images links in it
also, I would recommend serving the images through a web server like Nginx it would be better than serving them with code.

Comment: @Mark Setchell  thank you!I'm a newbie for using HTML language.If I want to add somt text at the top middle of each image,how should I modify my code?

Comment: Have a look here.. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

Comment: One more question,if I want to take the img_path variable as the parameter of hello_world function,how to pass this parameter to the hello_world function when executing app.run()？

Comment: Try opening a new question, showing your actual code and issues as it has probably diverged a lot from your original code above and relatively few people will look at comments on older questions.